# Is there a way to force gcc to start a new stack frame for a block?

Tags: c++, gcc, stack-frame

In embedded C++ code where RAM and hence stack space is limited, I often come across this situation:

```
void f(parameters) {
  if (condition) g(...);   // g uses lots of stack space
  else {
    int table[1000];
    // do something involving table
  }
}
```

Gcc allocates space for 'table' on the stack at the start of the function, which means that the stack must be large enough to accommodate both 'table' and the stack needed by g() even though these are not used at the same time.

I want to tell gcc to allocate a new stack frame for the { } block that comprises the else-part. That way the stack would only needs to be large enough to accommodate the larger of 'table' (plus other stack needed in the else part) and stack needed by the call to g(). Is there a way to do this?

My usual workaround is to turn the else-block into another function call and mark that function not to be inlined; but in some cases such a solution is ugly because the function needs a large number of parameters to pass values computed earlier in f().

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function, while asking the compiler to not expand it inline.

> but in some cases such a solution is ugly because the function needs a large number of parameters to pass values

Collect the parameters into a single class (or a few classes) to make it less ugly.

Or you can implicitly capture the paramaters in a lambda instead. Lambda does introduce its own ugliness though:

```
  if (condition) g(...);   // g uses lots of stack space
  else {
    [&]() {
      int table[1000];
      // do something involving table
    }();
  }
```

---

If dynamic storage is an option, then use that to allocate arrays whose size is significant in relation to the stack size.

Comment: That lambda still gets inlined, `__attribute__((noinline))` is needed to prevent that. See https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xtwkhQ

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of using a lambda. Dynamic allocation isn't an option in this case.